# Active Directory/LDAP replication Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am trying to setup replication between a Windows AD and OpenLDAP on Ubuntu.

Access to the Windows AD server seems to work OK, the OpenLDAP on Ubuntu also seems to work, however I am getting stuck on setting up the replication between both - I am new to AD/LDAP and there might be some concepts I'm missing.

I am able to list users on the remote (Windows) AD:

```
ldapsearch -x -h 192.168.1.200 -D 'CN=LDAP OpenVPN,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET' -w 'xxx' -b "DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET" cn
```

I setup the replication using the following config:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncrepl

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=001
  provider=ldap://192.168.1.200:389/
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="30 5 300 3"
  interval=00:00:05:00
  searchbase="CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET"
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="CN=LDAP OpenVPN,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET"
  credentials="xxx"

add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://192.168.1.200
```

And applied using:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f syncrepl.ldif
```

```
$ sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f syncrepl.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"

modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
```

However, replication seems to fail with the following error:

```
[16-02-2022 22:00:20] slapd debug  slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://192.168.1.200:389/ DN="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=net" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
[16-02-2022 22:00:20] slapd debug  do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc 49 quitting
[16-02-2022 22:00:21] slapd debug  slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://192.168.1.200:389/ DN="cn=openvpnldap,dc=domain,dc=net" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
[16-02-2022 22:00:21] slapd debug  do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc 49 quitting
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (12) Critical extension is unavailable
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrep2: rid=001 (12) Critical extension is unavailable
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 quitting
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (12) Critical extension is unavailable
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrep2: rid=001 (12) Critical extension is unavailable
[16-02-2022 22:00:22] slapd debug  do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 quitting
```

To give an idea of what I am trying to achieve:

- we have an on-premise network (192.168.1.0/24) with a Windows based Active Directory running on it
- we have a Google Cloud VPC network (10.0.0.0/8) with some resources running on it
- we have an IPSec tunnel running between the on-premise network and GCP network. Routes are properly setup and everything works like a charm
- we would like to access our on premise LDAP (192.168.1.200) from a VM, within Google Cloud VPC network - the point is to allow users from this AD to login to an OpenVPN server located on this VM
- we want authentication to keep working if we loose access to our on-premise network. To achieve this, the idea was to run a "proxy/cache" OpenLDAP on the same VM

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the replication fail already during the authentication phase `ldap_sasl_bind_s failed` try using ldaps instead of ldap or an encrypted SASL mechanism such as GSSAPI or DIGEST-MD5